# PHP pass variable through URL to be redirected

Tags: php, mysql, url

I need you help to solve the following situation.

I have search form that our user can use to search our database.

What I need is to pass the search variable in the url, so that I can retrieve it for my paginator.

Here is the code so far:
the problem with this code is that when I press the search button some time it take into account the echo and some times I have to select a second time for it to register the echo.

I presume it is because I am using `$_REQUEST` which can be interpreted as `$_GET` and/or `$_POST`.

What is the best practice and how can I achieve the result?

```
<form name="search_m" method="post" action="index.php?pg=result&a=<?php echo $_REQUEST['agency'];?>&pt=<?php echo $_REQUEST['property_type'];?>&pm=<?php echo $_REQUEST['property_market_status'];?>&tl=<?php echo $_REQUEST['type_listing'];?>&cp=<?php echo $_REQUEST['cp'];?>&r=<?php echo $_REQUEST['ref'];?>" >
    <select name="agency" class="styled-select">
        <option value=""> Select an Agent </option>
        <option value="remax"> Remax </option>
    </select>

    <select name="property_type" class="styled-select">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Property Type</option>
        <option value="1">Condo/Apartment</option>
        <option value="2">House</option>
        <option value="3">Land</option>
        <option value="4">Farm</option>
        <option value="5">Residential Farm</option>
        <option value="6">Garage</option>
        <option value="7">Yield property</option>
        <option value="8">Maisonette / Duplex</option>
    </select>

    <select name="property_market_status" class="styled-select">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Market Status:</option>
        <option value="1">Foreclosure</option>
        <option value="2">Coming Soon</option>
        <option value="3">New Build</option>
        <option value="4">Re-Built /Makeover</option>
        <option value="5">Used</option>
        <option value="6">Best Deal</option>
        <option value="7">In Auction</option>
    </select>  

    <select name="type_listing" class="styled-select">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Business:</option>
        <option value="Rent"> Rent </option>
        <option value="Sell"> Sell </option>
        <option value="Holiday Rental"> Holiday Rental </option>
    </select> 

    <select name="district" class="styled-select">
        <option value=""> district </option>
    </select>                                     

    <select name="concelho" class="styled-select">
        <option value=""> concelho </option>
    </select>

    <select name="freguesia" class="styled-select">
        <option value=""> freguesia </option>
    </select>


    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="cp" size="30px" placeholder="Postal Code:"/>
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="ref" size="30px" placeholder="Ref:"/>
        <select name="order_by" class="styled-select">
            <option value=""> Sort: ... </option>
            <option value=""> Sort: Agency </option>
            <option value=""> Sort: Location </option>
            <option value=""> Sort: More expensive </option>
            <option value=""> Sort: Cheapest price </option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" class="css_button" name="lista" value="Search">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use action query strings in form hidden field and post values with form like

```
action="index.php"

<input type="hidden" name="pg" value="result">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['agency'];?>">
```

and so on

Comment: thanks for you reply, how do I concatenate it in my URL? action="index.php?pg=result?<?php echo $_REQUEST['agency'];?> "?

Comment: change form method to get

Comment: I change my script take in consideration you advice, what is happening is that I am sent to my index page: ...index.php?agency=remax&a=&property_type=&.... it should stay on the same page ...index.php?pg=result and add my variables: ...index.php?pg=result&a=remax&pt=&pm=&tl=&cp=&r= any ideas why it does that?

Comment: also try $_REQUEST to $_GET if in query string and if form method post then use $_POST

Comment: I managed to correct my script with your advice using the hidden input and $_GET, thanks